# Dynamic query in django with "|" character in WHERE clause and variable in tablename

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I have a dynamic sql query running in my views.py and have already ran others that work fine. I am not worried about sql injections because this is a private website. However, the parameters in my And clause has the character "|" in it which throws the error:

```
Unknown column "X" in 'where clause'
```

I have looked at solutions but they all use non dynamic query which then prohibits me from making the tablename a variable.

Here is what I want:

```py
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
assembly_name = "peptides_proteins_000005"
group_id = 5
protein_id = "sp|P48740|MASP1_HUMAN"
qry = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE group_id = %i AND protein_id = %s" % (assembly_name, group_id, protein_id)
mycursor.execute(qry)
```

But this throws the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sp' in 'where clause'
```

When I try doing following the answers of similar questions I get this:

```py
qry = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE group_id = %i AND protein_id = %s"
mycursor.exectue(qry, (assembly_name, group_id, protein_id))
```

However, I still get this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Changing the %i to a %s fixes the error above but then I get a new error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''peptides_proteins_000005' WHERE group_id = 5 AND protein_id = 'sp|P48740|MASP1_' at line 1
```

And here is where the loop ends, because looking up this error online suggests to write something similar to the query at the top. Can anybody help me figure out a way to do this?

Comment: Add quotes around your string parameter.. `"SELECT * FROM %s WHERE group_id = %i AND protein_id = '%s'"`

Comment: @DanielM Thanks, just wondering, is there anyway to make this not vulnerable to sql injections, because I would prefer that however, this works fine!

Comment: yes, using prepared statements (the second way you mentioned, but still you need the quotes surrounding.

Comment: @DanielM I get the same error as I did before in the example. I think this error comes from the fact that the table name is also a variable?

Comment: You've tagged the question with Django. Any reason why you are not using the Django ORM?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes I only have read access to the database and It is much to large to import it all. There are around 6000 tables and I have already tried using importing them in but it takes too long.

Comment: You don't need to import the database. You can set up models against the existing db.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have tried using inspectdb to make the put the tables into models.py but it takes way to long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, there was not way to do this, so I had to put literal quotes around the %s.
My final code looked something like this:

```py
assembly_name = peptide_protein_formatter(assembly_name)

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    qry = "SELECT peptide_id,search_id FROM %s WHERE group_id = %s AND protein_id = '%s'" % (assembly_name, group_id, protein_id)

    mycursor.execute(qry)

    result = mycursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: I will accept my answer in two days unless someone wants to explain this better and give other solutions :)